# uncloseable Jquery UI modal form

Tags: jquery

Good day!

I just want to make a modal form unclosable if possible.

my aims are:

1. my webpage will detect the ip address of the user.
2. if the user is from another country, he will not be able to access the page, so a modal form will open up, and he will not be able to close it.

ways on how to close it are by it's close button and hitting esc right? (is there any other way?) How do i get rid of those?

Help anybody? thanks in advance!

Comment: And what happens if the user disables JS?

Comment: then it won't work i guess? lol. it's just a homework

Comment: My point really was to just illustrate that if a user wants to close it badly enough, he or she will find a way.  Anyway, you can probably just return false in the `close` callback, though I've never tried that myself.

Comment: Got your point there. Thanks dude! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind a function to beforeClose event of the dialog and prevent closing there.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({
            beforeClose: function(event, ui) { return false; }
    });
});​
```